# nodejs SSL handshake error on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to hit third party api splash payment from my nodejs application.
To hit api I am using response module

```
var options = {
    method: 'post',
    body: postData,
    json: true,
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "APIKEY" : config.splash_key
    }
}
request(options, function (err, res, body) {

    if (err) {
      console.error('error posting json: ', err);
      return cb( err  , null);

      // throw err;
    }

    return cb( body.response.errors  , body.response.data);
})
```

But it gives me error

```
Error: write EPROTO 140467444299648:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:772:
```

Please help

Comment: Did you check the same url with the api key in postman. is it working?

Comment: yes it is working on my local machine as well as on postman. Do I need some AWS configuration. I don't understand what to do

Comment: did not get what are you telling

Comment: See this [Post](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16196) it has some suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself, the problem was node version it was 9+ so I downgraded to 6.9. So problem was solved

Comment: I guess that's more of a workaround. See discussion in https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16196